# Suppressing em-dashs for recurrent authors and letter suffixes for years when using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am trying to generate a bibliography to summarize research in a certain field. The bibliography is required to be formatted Chicago style. Since this bibliography is not accompanying an actual document I'd like to suppress certain behaviours.

- *biblatex-chicago* replaces recurrent authors names with 3 em-dashes. This isn't desirable since this bibliography must be sorted *nyt* rather then *ynt*. Using the *dashed=false* option do not work (*biblatex-chicago* doesn't seem to support this option)
- To differentiate multiple bibliography entries by the same author in the same year *biblatex-chicago* adds a letter suffix to the year in the bib entry. This is not desirable since without in-text citations they don't serve any purpose.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibtest.bib}
@book{book1,
    Author = {Author B},
    Title = {Book 1},
    Year = {2008}}

@book{book2,
    Author = {Author B},
    Title = {Book 2},
    Year = {2009}}

@book{book3,
    Author = {Author A},
    Title = {Book 3},
    Year = {2010}}

@book{book4,
    Author = {Author A},
    Title = {Book 4},
    Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,sorting=ynt]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibtest.bib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

> B, Author. 2008. *Book 1*.
>
> ———, Author. 2009. *Book 2*.
>
> A, Author. 2010a. *Book 3*.
>
> ———, Author. 2010b. *Book 4*.

I'd like it to look like this:

> B, Author. 2008. *Book 1*.
>
> B, Author. 2009. *Book 2*.
>
> A, Author. 2010. *Book 3*.
>
> A, Author. 2010. *Book 4*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` unfortunately doesn't have a `dashed` option like the standard styles. To avoid printing the dash, you can clear `\bbx@lasthash` before printing each entry using the `\AtEveryBibitem` hook. `\bbx@lasthash` normally expands to the name hash of the last entry. It is used by the drivers for dash checks.

The alphabetic year suffix used for disambiguation corresponds to the `extrayear` field. It can be cleared with `\AtEveryBibitem` as well.

Just add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extrayear}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 8):

To remove the letter suffix after the year, add the following to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{}
```

Comment: This stopped working for me and I had to use `extradate` instead of `extrayear`.

Comment: This answer for me when every alternative solution on here didn't.  If someone can explain why different solutions are working for some people and not for others, I'm sure that would be helpful.

Comment: Conceptually, it does not feel nice to suppress a field from the output by making its field format empty, but it works (because `biblatex` explicitly checks for that case). To completely get rid of a field it is usually nicer to use a sourcemap (in case it's an input field), tell Biber not to generate the field (in case it is an auto-generated field like `extradate`) or to stop it being read from the `.bbl` file with `\DeclareFieldInputHandler{extradate}{\def\NewValue{}}`, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550110/35864