# Synchronizing bibliography labels accross refsections

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

For my dissertation I have the requirement that all of my own articles that are cited in the text are included in the general references section and all of my own articles are included in an extra references section. I'm using biblatex. To collect all of my paper in the extra section I use keyword filtering in combination with `\nocite{*}`. To prevent the `\nocite{*}` to propagate to the general references, I use a “refsection”. That works perfect except that the labels are not synchronized. How can I synchronize the labels? What would be the correct approach to achieve what I have to fulfill?

The following code/picture illustrates the problem:

[image: Image illustrating the problem]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@Article{MyArticleA,
  Title                    = {Article A},
  Author                   = {Me},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Number                   = {13},
  Pages                    = {156},
}
@Article{MyArticleB,
  Title                    = {Article B},
  Author                   = {Me},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Number                   = {14},
  Pages                    = {228},
}
@Article{MyArticleC,
  Title                    = {Article C},
  Author                   = {Me},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Number                   = {15},
  Pages                    = {111},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{testbib}

\begin{document}

\noindent Citation of Article B: \cite{MyArticleB}; Citation of Article C: \cite{MyArticleC}

\printbibliography

\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={My Publications}]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy answer to your title question. `refsections` were made to be absolutely separate from each other, so there is no obvious way to synchronise the labels (save for retreating to the `shorthand` or `label` fields, but that is hardly going to be automatic). If you employ some more filtering, you might be able to drop the `refsection`s.

Comment: If you are OK with manually `\nocite`ing your publications, you should be able to do it with `refsegments`.

Comment: @moewe This is what I am trying to avoid, still hoping for a solution with `\nocite{*}`. I would expect it being a common task, but it seems I'm wrong on that.

Comment: I think questions like that creep up once in a while. You are facing a technical limitation of `\nocite` and `refsection` here though. (So no matter how popular this feature might be, those would still have to be overcome.) You might want to consider alternative approaches to your actual problem such as the one in [Biblatex: using “dashed” in one refsection but not another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127498/35864).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125744/35864 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111291/35864 in combination with http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864.

Comment: @moewe I do not have to stick to the refsection approach if another automatic solution is possible. What I do not see is a possibility to use filters without manually marking entries that appear _only_ in the additional bibliography. What I would need is a filter for the general bibliography that filters out entries that have not been cited. Anyway, I have to check your links now.

Comment: @moewe To your links: The first four deal with ordinary filters what would not help without additional capabilities, e.g. filtering based on “already cited” what is described in your last link. That's not a fully automatic solution but at least it saves a lot of effort. What I have to do is to add a filter based on “already cited” for the general bib and the filter “my work” that is already present in my original files for the extra bib. Then I only have to get rid of additional entries that may occur due to the `\nocite{*}` in the extra bib. Thanks so far, still open for automatic solutions.

Comment: In that case I think the very last link is as automatic as it gets

Comment: @moewe Without reading your answer (I'll do tomorrow, I have to leave office now) I had a mistake in my considerations. The solution with the two independent filters as described works. Thanks for all the hints.

Comment: The solution given by @moewe solves my particular problem but does not reflect the title of the question. Should I change the title of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `refsection`s are kept completely independent and separate of each other, there is no easy way of making the labels align between two different `refsection`s. Sometimes using `refsegments`, which are not kept separate, can help solve the problem. In the case at hand, though, `refsegment`s will not do what we want.

In order to keep the `\nocite{*}`, we need to be able to distinguish works that were really (i.e. visibly) `\cite`d from those added only via `\nocite`. A easy solution for this is explained in [How to split bibliography into “works cited” and “works not cited”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864)

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
```

In your MWE that will already be enough, but maybe we also need a way to filter only *your* publications. You can get inspired by [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864), [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/35864), [How to print a bibliography for a particular author only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125744/35864). The solution here is based on the `fullhash` calculated by Biber, it can identify names as uniquely as Biber allows for

```
\defbibcheck{mywork}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{fullhash}{e06f6e5a8c1d5204dea326aa5f4f8d17}
    {}
    {\skipentry}
}
```

If you use different formats/versions of your name, for example "A. Uthor", "Anne Uthor" and "Anne K. Uthor" you will have to account for all of these. You can find the `namehash` generated for a name in the `.bbl` file.
For example

```
\defbibcheck{mywork}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequalstr{fullhash}{e06f6e5a8c1d5204dea326aa5f4f8d17}} or test {\iffieldequalstr{fullhash}{fb328aaf7bc297844ac66ad9e0844e1b}}}
    {}
    {\skipentry}
}
```

will classify both "Anne Uthor" as well as "Anne K. Uthor" as your publication.

Now the "normal" bibliography is

```
\printbibliography[category=cited]
```

and your list of publications is

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={My Publications},check=mywork]
```

Where of course the actual position of `\nocite{*}` in your document does not really matter.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{MyArticleA,
  Title                    = {Article A},
  Author                   = {Anne Uthor},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Number                   = {13},
  Pages                    = {156},
}
@Article{MyArticleB,
  Title                    = {Article B},
  Author                   = {Anne Uthor},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Number                   = {14},
  Pages                    = {228},
}
@Article{MyArticleC,
  Title                    = {Article C},
  Author                   = {Anne Uthor},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Number                   = {15},
  Pages                    = {111},
}
@Article{MyArticleD,
  Title                    = {Article D},
  Author                   = {Willard Riter},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Number                   = {16},
  Pages                    = {112-115},
}
@Article{MyArticleE,
  Title                    = {Article E},
  Author                   = {Willard Riter},
  Journal                  = {Nature},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Number                   = {17},
  Pages                    = {112-115},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\defbibcheck{mywork}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{fullhash}{e06f6e5a8c1d5204dea326aa5f4f8d17}
    {}
    {\skipentry}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent Citation of Article B: \cite{MyArticleB}; Citation of Article C: \cite{MyArticleC} and \cite{MyArticleE}

\printbibliography[category=cited]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={My Publications},check=mywork]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even though `MyArticleD` is in the `.bib` file it does not appear in either of the lists, because it is neither one of your (viz. Anne Uthor's) publications nor one of the works cited.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I implemented it a bit different. I use a keyword filter for my own publications since they already have a keyword that marks them accordingly. Nevertheless, filtering based on names or name hashes is another option as well.

Comment: @Chris Using a keyword would have been the easy option. But since I wasn't too sure what you were using and I didn't find any solution here using `fullhash` I thought it would be a nice touch.

Comment: It is. But what is the benefit of using hashes over name strings? I guess implementation-wise it makes a difference, but for the user string and hash are the same, aren't they?

Comment: @Chris Hashes are far more fancy `;-)`. They were explicitly designed to uniquely identify authors (save for different spellings, use of initials etc., of course). Plus, in this case string comparison - if done right, as in the answers I linked to - is slightly longer than comparing hashes. The only drawback I see is that you have to get the hash from the `.bbl` once whereas you will have no problem finding the correct input for the string comparison.

Comment: Then maybe I misunderstood, but you are using several hashes to cover different use of initials in your example above. How can the hash be independent of spelling etc.?

Comment: @Chris It isn't independent of spelling and use of additional initials, that is why I said "save for different spellings" above; maybe the "uniquely identify" bit was a bit too strong a claim. Anyway, the idea is that "Anne Uthor" and "Uthor, Anne" in the `.bib` file both give the same hash.

Comment: OK, I understand, kind of a normalized name. Thanks for the explanation. Any suggestions on how to deal with the question title (see comment below question)?

Comment: @Chris Yes, the "normalised name" is a much better description. I thought about the title thing for a bit, but couldn't come up with something nice. If you cannot think of anything that sums up the newly developed question, leave it for now.