# Removing suffix in authoryear-ibid eg. (2011a)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am having a hard time removing the suffix in the year in authoryear-ibid citation as you can see in the following picture.

[image: Citation Image]

This is the code I use for biblatex:

```
\usepackage[
    citestyle=verbose-ibid, 
    bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, 
    backend=biber]
    {biblatex}
```

I know that this suffix apperantly should be controllable by the `labeldateparts` but apperantly it does not take effect. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found this: which works kinda good for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63500/suppress-year-label-letter-in-biblatex-author-year-styles-on-a-per-bibliography if no one else has a better solution this will be logged as my answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! For future questions it's helpful to post a compilable minimal document that shows what you're doing, rather than a code fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done simply by clearing the `extradate` field. Note that this solution works for your particular use case, but in other situations it might lead to unexpected results. In this case, [the solution by moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502782/2693) is more robust. See the comments there for some discussion.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Chomsky1986,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Barriers},
    Year = {1986}}

@book{Chomsky1986b,
    Address = {New York},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Praeger},
    Title = {Knowledge of Language: its nature, origin and use},
    Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    citestyle=verbose-ibid, 
    bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, 
]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{}
\begin{document}
\autocite{Chomsky1986b,Chomsky1986}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not too fond of suppressing fields with en empty field format, here is a solution that redefines the involved commands directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  citestyle=verbose-ibid,
  bibstyle=authoryear-ibid,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printdate}}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}[2]{#1}%


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, Donald E. (1986). Computers & Typesetting. Vol. B: TeX: The Program. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley.//— (1986). Computers & Typesetting. Vol. C: The METAFONTbook. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley.]

A slightly less aggressive approach would still leave traces of `labeldate` by only redefining `date+extradate` as follows (and leaving `bbx:ifmergeddate` unchanged)

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdate}
         {\printlabeldate}}}}%
```

---

A different, but more direct, way to delete the extra date would be

```
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{extradate}{\def\NewValue{}}
```

Comment: Apart from the conceptual reasons for not doing this by clearing the field format, are there empirical downsides to doing it that way? It's certainly a more user-accessible way of doing it.

Comment: @AlanMunn There shouldn't be a lot (for almost all intents and purposes). `\printfield` checks if the field format is empty and then behaves as if the field didn't exist. `\iffieldundef` checks might give the wrong result, but most styles keep those at a minimum. A difference between the two approaches can be seen if you only load `style=authoryear-comp,`. Then `\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}`. `\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{}` leaves a comma in the output, but `\DeclareFieldInputHandler{extradate}{\def\NewValue{}}` doesn't (of course both results are wrong, so ...).

Comment: I have used the clearfield method by @AlanMunn but your approach is quite sophisticated but for my usage I prefer it a bit simplistic. Sadly i cant flag both answers to be true :(

Comment: @AlanMunn Here is an example that shows two problematic uses of an empty field format: https://gist.github.com/moewew/f07c3add09939506071f25ff459af897

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I've added a link to your answer in mine so that people don't overgeneralize the solution.